# Why custom dropdown isn't opening on click?

Tags: javascript, css

I built out this custom dropdown for a filter, but for some reason, the dropdown isn't dropping down. `.open` is being appended to the selector... but I'm missing something.

```js
//dropdown
let current_story = "",
  current_year = "";

for (const dropdown of document.querySelectorAll(
  ".custom__select-wrapper:not(.clearFilter)"
)) {
  dropdown.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.querySelector(".custom__select").classList.toggle("open");
  });
}

for (const option of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__option")) {
  option.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (!this.classList.contains("selected")) {
      this.parentNode
        .querySelector(".custom__option.selected")
        .classList.remove("selected");
      this.classList.add("selected");
      this.closest(".custom__select").querySelector(
        ".custom__select-trigger h6"
      ).textContent = this.textContent;
      if (this.getAttribute("data-year")) {
        current_year = this.dataset["year"];
        yearFilter(this.dataset["year"]);
      } else {
        current_story = this.dataset["type"];
        storyFilter(this.dataset["type"]);
      }
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  for (const select of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__select")) {
    if (!select.contains(e.target)) {
      select.classList.remove("open");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  font-family: "motiva-sans" sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.stretched-link::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  content: "";
}

.d-flex {
  display: -webkit-box !important;
  display: -ms-flexbox !important;
  display: flex !important;
}

.align-items-stretch {
  -webkit-box-align: stretch !important;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch !important;
  align-items: stretch !important;
}

.mx-auto {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.icon-lg {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.text-white {
  color: white;
}

.email {
  color: #005fec;
}

.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}

.tt-normal {
  text-transform: none;
}

.tt-uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.fw-normal {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.fw-bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.fw-bolder {
  font-weight: 800;
}

.fw-boldest {
  font-weight: 900;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "motiva-sans";
  src: url("https://use.typekit.net/af/b996c1/00000000000000003b9b3552/27/l?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n3&v=3")
      format("woff2"),
    url("https://use.typekit.net/af/b996c1/00000000000000003b9b3552/27/d?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n3&v=3")
      format("woff"),
    url("https://use.typekit.net/af/b996c1/00000000000000003b9b3552/27/a?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n3&v=3")
      format("opentype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "motiva-sans";
  src: url("https://use.typekit.net/af/c1bab1/00000000000000003b9b354f/27/l?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n4&v=3")
      format("woff2"),
    url("https://use.typekit.net/af/c1bab1/00000000000000003b9b354f/27/d?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n4&v=3")
      format("woff"),
    url("https://use.typekit.net/af/c1bab1/00000000000000003b9b354f/27/a?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n4&v=3")
      format("opentype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "motiva-sans";
  src: url("https://use.typekit.net/af/f499a5/00000000000000003b9b3555/27/l?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n7&v=3")
      format("woff2"),
    url("https://use.typekit.net/af/f499a5/00000000000000003b9b3555/27/d?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n7&v=3")
      format("woff"),
    url("https://use.typekit.net/af/f499a5/00000000000000003b9b3555/27/a?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n7&v=3")
      format("opentype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "motiva-sans";
  src: url("https://use.typekit.net/af/218e23/00000000000000003b9b3553/27/l?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n8&v=3")
      format("woff2"),
    url("https://use.typekit.net/af/218e23/00000000000000003b9b3553/27/d?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n8&v=3")
      format("woff"),
    url("https://use.typekit.net/af/218e23/00000000000000003b9b3553/27/a?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n8&v=3")
      format("opentype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-display: swap;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .news-header {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 30vh;
    margin: 200px auto 10px;
  }
  .news-header .news-header__content {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: #005fec;
  }
  .news-header__title h6 {
    font-weight: weight(bold);
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .news-header__slogan {
    margin: 24px 0 16px;
  }
  .news-header__slogan h1 {
    font-weight: weight(bold);
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 44px;
  }
  .news-header__subtitle h5 {
    font-weight: weight(normal);
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 36px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .news-header__article {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 20vh;
    margin: 150px auto 10px;
  }
  .news-header__content {
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 991px) {
  .news-header__slogan h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 68px;
  }
  .news-header__subtitle h5 {
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 40px;
  }
}

.filtered .article {
  display: none;
}

.filtered .article.show {
  display: block;
}

.no-cards {
  background: #005fec;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.no-cards > h4 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.load-more-button {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 3em auto;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .nextcard {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000a70;
    padding: 40px 32px 32px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 12px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0px 12px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.2s ease;
    transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.2s ease;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease, -webkit-box-shadow 0.2s ease;
    margin: 20px 0;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
  }
  .nextcard__content {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .nextcard__logo {
    height: 80px;
    width: 136px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .nextcard__logo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .nextcard__date {
    color: #005fec;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 800;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 12px;
    margin: 6em 0 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .nextcard__title h4 {
    color: #000a70;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin: 0 0 2em;
  }
  .nextcard__footer {
    margin-top: auto;
  }
  .nextcard__icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    width: 24px;
  }
  .nextcard__icon--spacer {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  }
  .nextcard__icon:hover .nextcard__icon--spacer {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .nextcard:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  }
  .nextcard:hover .nextcard__content .nextcard__title h4 {
    color: #005fec;
  }
  .nextcard--no-link:hover .nextcard__content .nextcard__title h4 {
    color: #000a70;
  }
  .nextcard--no-link:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 12px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0px 12px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  }
}

button.clear {
  border: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

#selectedFilter {
  color: #005fec;
}

.filter__settings {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.custom__select-wrapper h6 {
  padding: 0 3px;
  color: #a1b4c4;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.custom__select {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.custom__select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.custom__select-trigger {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom__select-wrapper h6,
.custom__select-trigger h6 {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.custom__select-trigger h6 {
  color: #005fec;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.custom__select-wrapper #selectedFilter {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #005fec;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 0;
}

.custom__options {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #005fec;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.custom__options:before,
.custom__options:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 11px;
  border: 11px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #005fec;
}

.custom__options.active {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
}

.custom__select-trigger,
.custom__option {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #005fec;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.custom__select.open .custom__options {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: all;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.custom__option {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 22px 0 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  margin: 1.5em 0;
}

.custom__option:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom__option.selected {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.custom__option.selected::before {
  content: "•";
  margin-left: -12px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

/* arrow */
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

.arrow::before,
.arrow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 0.1rem;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.arrow::before {
  left: -2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #394a6d;
}

.arrow::after {
  left: 2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: #394a6d;
}

.open .arrow::before {
  left: -2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.open .arrow::after {
  left: 2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.arrow::after {
  left: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: #394a6d;
}

.open .arrow::before {
  left: -2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.open .arrow::after {
  left: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .filter__settings {
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .custom__select-trigger {
    -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
    -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .filter__settings .custom__select-wrapper {
    margin: 0 2em;
  }
  .custom__select-wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .custom__select-wrapper:last-child {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

.article {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="filter">
  <div class="filter__settings">
    <div class="custom__select-wrapper">
      <h6>filter by</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="custom__select-wrapper">
      <div class="custom__select story-sel selector">
        <div class="custom__select-trigger">
          <h6>Story Type</h6>
          <div class="arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom__options dropdown story-selector" id="storyFilter">
          <span class="custom__option selected" data-type="all">All</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-type="news">News and Media</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-type="analysis">Analysis</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-type="press">Press Releases</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom__select-wrapper">
      <div class="custom__select year-sel selector">
        <div class="custom__select-trigger">
          <h6>Year</h6>
          <div class="arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom__options dropdown year-selector" id="yearFilter">
          <span class="custom__option selected" data-year="all">All</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2021">2021</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2020">2020</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2019">2019</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2018">2018</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2017">2017</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2016">2016</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2015">2015</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2014">2014</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2013">2013</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2012">2012</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2011">2011</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2010">2010</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2009">2009</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2008">2008</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2007">2007</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2006">2006</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom__select-wrapper clearFilter">
      <h6 class="clear hidden" id="selectedFilter" onclick="clearSelection()">clear filters</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `display: none;` inside `.custom__options` class. Just remove it.

```js
//dropdown
let current_story = "",
  current_year = "";

for (const dropdown of document.querySelectorAll(
  ".custom__select-wrapper:not(.clearFilter)"
)) {
  dropdown.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.querySelector(".custom__select").classList.toggle("open");
  });
}

for (const option of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__option")) {
  option.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (!this.classList.contains("selected")) {
      this.parentNode
        .querySelector(".custom__option.selected")
        .classList.remove("selected");
      this.classList.add("selected");
      this.closest(".custom__select").querySelector(
        ".custom__select-trigger h6"
      ).textContent = this.textContent;
      if (this.getAttribute("data-year")) {
        current_year = this.dataset["year"];
        yearFilter(this.dataset["year"]);
      } else {
        current_story = this.dataset["type"];
        storyFilter(this.dataset["type"]);
      }
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  for (const select of document.querySelectorAll(".custom__select")) {
    if (!select.contains(e.target)) {
      select.classList.remove("open");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  font-family: "motiva-sans" sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.stretched-link::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  content: "";
}

.d-flex {
  display: -webkit-box !important;
  display: -ms-flexbox !important;
  display: flex !important;
}

.align-items-stretch {
  -webkit-box-align: stretch !important;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch !important;
  align-items: stretch !important;
}

.mx-auto {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.icon-lg {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.text-white {
  color: white;
}

.email {
  color: #005fec;
}

.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}

.tt-normal {
  text-transform: none;
}

.tt-uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.fw-normal {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.fw-bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.fw-bolder {
  font-weight: 800;
}

.fw-boldest {
  font-weight: 900;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "motiva-sans";
  src: url("https://use.typekit.net/af/b996c1/00000000000000003b9b3552/27/l?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n3&v=3")
      format("woff2"),
    url("https://use.typekit.net/af/b996c1/00000000000000003b9b3552/27/d?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n3&v=3")
      format("woff"),
    url("https://use.typekit.net/af/b996c1/00000000000000003b9b3552/27/a?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n3&v=3")
      format("opentype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "motiva-sans";
  src: url("https://use.typekit.net/af/c1bab1/00000000000000003b9b354f/27/l?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n4&v=3")
      format("woff2"),
    url("https://use.typekit.net/af/c1bab1/00000000000000003b9b354f/27/d?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n4&v=3")
      format("woff"),
    url("https://use.typekit.net/af/c1bab1/00000000000000003b9b354f/27/a?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n4&v=3")
      format("opentype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "motiva-sans";
  src: url("https://use.typekit.net/af/f499a5/00000000000000003b9b3555/27/l?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n7&v=3")
      format("woff2"),
    url("https://use.typekit.net/af/f499a5/00000000000000003b9b3555/27/d?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n7&v=3")
      format("woff"),
    url("https://use.typekit.net/af/f499a5/00000000000000003b9b3555/27/a?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n7&v=3")
      format("opentype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "motiva-sans";
  src: url("https://use.typekit.net/af/218e23/00000000000000003b9b3553/27/l?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n8&v=3")
      format("woff2"),
    url("https://use.typekit.net/af/218e23/00000000000000003b9b3553/27/d?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n8&v=3")
      format("woff"),
    url("https://use.typekit.net/af/218e23/00000000000000003b9b3553/27/a?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n8&v=3")
      format("opentype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-display: swap;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .news-header {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 30vh;
    margin: 200px auto 10px;
  }
  .news-header .news-header__content {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: #005fec;
  }
  .news-header__title h6 {
    font-weight: weight(bold);
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .news-header__slogan {
    margin: 24px 0 16px;
  }
  .news-header__slogan h1 {
    font-weight: weight(bold);
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 44px;
  }
  .news-header__subtitle h5 {
    font-weight: weight(normal);
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 36px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .news-header__article {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 20vh;
    margin: 150px auto 10px;
  }
  .news-header__content {
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 991px) {
  .news-header__slogan h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 68px;
  }
  .news-header__subtitle h5 {
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 40px;
  }
}

.filtered .article {
  display: none;
}

.filtered .article.show {
  display: block;
}

.no-cards {
  background: #005fec;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.no-cards > h4 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.load-more-button {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 3em auto;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .nextcard {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000a70;
    padding: 40px 32px 32px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 12px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0px 12px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.2s ease;
    transition: -webkit-box-shadow 0.2s ease;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease, -webkit-box-shadow 0.2s ease;
    margin: 20px 0;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
  }
  .nextcard__content {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .nextcard__logo {
    height: 80px;
    width: 136px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .nextcard__logo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .nextcard__date {
    color: #005fec;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 800;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 12px;
    margin: 6em 0 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .nextcard__title h4 {
    color: #000a70;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin: 0 0 2em;
  }
  .nextcard__footer {
    margin-top: auto;
  }
  .nextcard__icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    width: 24px;
  }
  .nextcard__icon--spacer {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  }
  .nextcard__icon:hover .nextcard__icon--spacer {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .nextcard:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  }
  .nextcard:hover .nextcard__content .nextcard__title h4 {
    color: #005fec;
  }
  .nextcard--no-link:hover .nextcard__content .nextcard__title h4 {
    color: #000a70;
  }
  .nextcard--no-link:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 12px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0px 12px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  }
}

button.clear {
  border: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

#selectedFilter {
  color: #005fec;
}

.filter__settings {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.custom__select-wrapper h6 {
  padding: 0 3px;
  color: #a1b4c4;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.custom__select {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.custom__select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.custom__select-trigger {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom__select-wrapper h6,
.custom__select-trigger h6 {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.custom__select-trigger h6 {
  color: #005fec;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.custom__select-wrapper #selectedFilter {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #005fec;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 0;
}

.custom__options {
  position: absolute;
/*  display: none; */
  background-color: #005fec;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.custom__options:before,
.custom__options:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 11px;
  border: 11px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #005fec;
}

.custom__options.active {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10;
}

.custom__select-trigger,
.custom__option {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #005fec;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.custom__select.open .custom__options {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: all;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.custom__option {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 22px 0 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  margin: 1.5em 0;
}

.custom__option:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom__option.selected {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.custom__option.selected::before {
  content: "•";
  margin-left: -12px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

/* arrow */
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

.arrow::before,
.arrow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 0.1rem;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.arrow::before {
  left: -2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #394a6d;
}

.arrow::after {
  left: 2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: #394a6d;
}

.open .arrow::before {
  left: -2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.open .arrow::after {
  left: 2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.arrow::after {
  left: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: #394a6d;
}

.open .arrow::before {
  left: -2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.open .arrow::after {
  left: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .filter__settings {
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .custom__select-trigger {
    -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
    -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .filter__settings .custom__select-wrapper {
    margin: 0 2em;
  }
  .custom__select-wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .custom__select-wrapper:last-child {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

.article {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="filter">
  <div class="filter__settings">
    <div class="custom__select-wrapper">
      <h6>filter by</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="custom__select-wrapper">
      <div class="custom__select story-sel selector">
        <div class="custom__select-trigger">
          <h6>Story Type</h6>
          <div class="arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom__options dropdown story-selector" id="storyFilter">
          <span class="custom__option selected" data-type="all">All</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-type="news">News and Media</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-type="analysis">Analysis</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-type="press">Press Releases</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom__select-wrapper">
      <div class="custom__select year-sel selector">
        <div class="custom__select-trigger">
          <h6>Year</h6>
          <div class="arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom__options dropdown year-selector" id="yearFilter">
          <span class="custom__option selected" data-year="all">All</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2021">2021</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2020">2020</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2019">2019</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2018">2018</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2017">2017</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2016">2016</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2015">2015</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2014">2014</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2013">2013</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2012">2012</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2011">2011</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2010">2010</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2009">2009</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2008">2008</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2007">2007</span>
          <span class="custom__option" data-year="2006">2006</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="custom__select-wrapper clearFilter">
      <h6 class="clear hidden" id="selectedFilter" onclick="clearSelection()">clear filters</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```